# Pass value from vuejs view once and use common for all controllers in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

After logging in, I let it go to the home page to choose to access one of the two tools:

```
<button @click="checkTool(1)" class="btn btn-lg mr-2">Tool 1</button>
<button @click="checkTool(2)" class="btn btn-lg">Tool 2</button>

methods: {
   checkTool(id) {
      localStorage.setItem("idTool", id);
      this.$router.push({ path: "/dashboard" });
   }
}
```

When the user selects the tool, I will set the idTool to `localStorage`.
And go to the `dashboard` page.

In laravel i have 4 controller :

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UserController extends Controller
{

}
```

**ProductController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    
}
```

**TicketController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TicketCodeController extends Controller
{
    
}
```

Normally I would give it a route api and then use `axios` to pass the value from the view to the controller and use `$request` to get that value out.

Now I want to get that `idTool` through the controller to check if it has permission under that `idTool`, actually this is very easy..But the problem here is that I don't want to have to pass `idTool` in every api call to check..Is there a way to get `idTool` and use it for all `controllers`? I have researched about `Interface` but still can't solve the problem. Please give me your opinion.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set a session with idTool value on backend-laravel and check it as a middleware for every request.
This is first option I can suggest at the moment.